# How do i access instance variables from classes in other files?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, instance-variables

I am trying to access instance variables from a class which is in a file called `quest.py`.

In the current file `room.py`, I am trying to perform a boolean statement between variables of each class, but every time I try to call for the variable in the `quest.py` file, it simply says I have no defined it yet.

However, I have a separate file called `simulation.py` which imports all of these files and creates objects for these classes, and this is the file I am running.

For example, I run the simulation file which is immediately supposed to draw a picture of a room and provide the description of the room you are in.

But this description changes depending on whether or not a quest has been completed in this room.

But I cannot access these descriptions which are located in the quest class, in this current room class.

Any ideas?? I am ultimately trying to run this draw function.

I cannot write any code outside of the classes in these separate files. The majority of this code has to be in the simulation file.

> room.py:

```
class Room
    def __init__(self, name):
        """Initialises a room. ."""
        self.name = name
        self.north = "N" ##Exits...
        self.south = "-"
        self.east = "|"
        self.west = "|"
    def get_short_desc(self):
        desc = 'There is nothing in this room.'
        if q.get_room_name() == self.name:
            if q.quest_complete == True:
                desc = self.after
            elif q.quest_complete == False:
                desc = self.before
        return desc
    def draw(self):
        """ Creates a drawing depicting the exits in each room."""
        print("+---------{}{}---------+".format(self.north,self.north))
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("{}                    {}".format(self.east,self.west)) ## The list of east and west changes depending on the room
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("|                    |")
        print("+---------{}{}---------+".format(self.south,self.south))
        print("You are standing at the {}.".format(self.name)) # the name of the room
        desc = r.get_short_desc()
        print(desc)
        return self.name
```

> quest.py:

```
class Quest

    def __init__(self, reward, action, desc, before, after, req, fail_msg,           pass_msg, room):
        """ Initialises a quest."""
        self.reward = reward
        self.action = action
        self.desc = desc
        self.before = before
        self.after = after
        self.req = req
        self.fail_msg = fail_msg
        self.pass_msg = pass_msg
        self.room = room
        self.quest_complete = False
    def get_room_name(self):
        return self.room  #so i can access the instance variable of "room" in other classes
```

The previous code is imported into a simulation.py file, which is ran:

```
    from room import Room
    from quest import Quest
    r = Room(rooms[3]) ##one room example
    q = Quest(quest_list[0][0],quest_list[0][1],quest_list[0][2],quest_list[0][3],quest_list[0][4],quest_list[0][5],quest_list[0][6],quest_list[0][7],quest_list[0][8]) ##i have already created a list containing quests, this is just one quest example
    r.draw()
```

The expected output is:

```
    +---------NN---------+
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    |                    |
    +--------------------+
    You are standing at the Entrance.
    There is nothing in this room
```

Returns a string containing a short description of the room. This description changes based on whether or not a relevant quest has been completed in this room. If there are no quests that are relevant to this room, this should return:  `There is nothing in this room.` The error I recieve is :

> ""You are standing at the Entrance.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "simulation.py", line 1, in
>   
>       from room import Room
>
> File "/home/andrewb/Documents/vscode.py/Adventure_Scaffold/room.py",
>   line 89, in 
>       r.draw()
>
> File "/home/andrewb/Documents/vscode.py/Adventure_Scaffold/room.py",
>   line 72, in draw
>       desc = r.get_short_desc()
>
> File "/home/andrewb/Documents/vscode.py/Adventure_Scaffold/room.py",
>   line 20, in get_short_desc
>       if q.get_room_name() == self.name: NameError: name 'q' is not defined""

Comment: In `get_short_desc()` you are using a variable `q` which isn't defined (at least not in the shown code). Is this your try to access a `Quest` object?

Comment: Please create a runnable example that demonstrates the problem and post it including the full error out.

Comment: it is always good idea to do `get_short_desc(instance_of _quest)` and then there is no problem with classes from other files.

Comment: despite defining q in the simulation file, the error message still says i have not defined it

Comment: you should use `def get_short_desc(self, q)` and later `r.get_short_desc(q)` - it prefered way to do this.

Comment: where is this method(in what class defined)?:get_room_name() . Post the whole code

Comment: And constructor of Room class takes name as parameter, i dont see you passing it in the simultion.py file.

Comment: The constructor of room takes rooms[3] which i have defined already (not seen in this code),i have also added the method: get_room_name()

Comment: How have you imported Query in Room? As q?

Comment: If i import Quest as q, it then says:   File "room.py", line 20, in get_short_desc
    if q.get_room_name() == self.name:
TypeError: get_room_name() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.                           But i have already created the quest object in the simulation.py file